# Do I need to create each application iOS Certificates for App Store publishing?

Tags: swift

I having apple developer account also I already created iOS Certificate and provisional profile. Now, I am planing to publishing my second application, here do I need to create new iOS Certificate (Dev/ Prod) and Provisional Profile (Dev/Prod)?

Comment: No need to create new iOS Certificate (Dev/ Prod). but for different app requires different provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous iOS certificate will work but for every new application, you need to create a new App ID and then new provisional profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do, different app requires different provisioning profiles

Comment: What about iOS Certificates? @Lu_

Comment: Your main cert will do